# Calculate x offset on FormattedText instance with TextAlignment.Center

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've a class which inherits from `Shape` and also needs to precisely draw some multiline text within the `OnRender(DrawingContect drawingContext)` method.

I can fill a rectangle which exactly fills the rectangular size of the text:

[image]

And the relevant simplified code snippet:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    ...

    var formattedText = new FormattedText(
        Text,
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft
            ? FlowDirection.RightToLeft
            : FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        TypeFace,
        FontSize,
        TextBrush
    );
    formattedText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
    formattedText.Trimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis;
    formattedText.SetFontWeight(FontWeight);
    formattedText.MaxTextWidth = Width;
    formattedText.MaxTextHeight = Height;

    ...

    DrawShape(
        drawingContext,
        new List<Point>
        {
            new Point(0, 0),
            new Point(formattedText.Width, 0),
            new Point(formattedText.Width, formattedText.Height),
            new Point(0, formattedText.Height)
        },
        brush,
        pen
    );
    drawingContext.DrawText(formattedText, new Point(0, 0));

    ... 
}

void DrawShape(DrawingContext dc, List<Point> points, Brush fill, Pen pen)
{
    var streamGeometry = new StreamGeometry();
    using (var ctx = streamGeometry.Open())
    {
        ctx.BeginFigure(points[0], true, true);
        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            ctx.LineTo(point, true, true);
        }
    }
    streamGeometry.Freeze();
    dc.DrawGeometry(fill, pen, streamGeometry);
}
```

My problem is when I try to use the same code above but with `TextAlignment.Center` I'm unable to correctly position that rectangle behind the text:

[image]

How can I get the x offset to correctly draw that rectangle?

This isn't what I'm trying to achieve, but is a simplified example which highlights the issue.

Comment: Just curious: Why are you not using [`DrawingContext.DrawRectangle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.drawrectangle?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: It's because the real thing I'm trying to make doesn't have rectangles. Figured it would be better to show `DrawShape` which I'm really using if there's an error within that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two properties, [`OverhandLeading`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.formattedtext.overhangleading) and [`OverhandTrailing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.formattedtext.overhangtrailing) which provide this information:

[image]

I overlooked these originally as they weren't giving me the expected behaviour, but turns out I had some incorrect logic to calculate my rotation centre point on my real shape.

So, for the example above, the points would be:

```
new Point(formattedText.OverhangLeading, 0),
new Point(formattedText.Width - formattedText.OverhangTrailing, 0),
new Point(formattedText.Width - formattedText.OverhangTrailing, formattedText.Height),
new Point(formattedText.OverhangLeading, formattedText.Height)
```